# Which test applicable to compare means across time series?

Tags: time-series, anova, mean

I am currently writing my Master thesis and seek some advise how to best analyse my data and what the appropriate test for significance would be.

To give you some background: I want to analyse whether a certain type of event has a significant impact on the trading volume of a company's stock price. For this, I have compiled a sample of ~400 different companies, each with a unique company ticker. For every company, I have an event date - the date at which the event happens which I want to analyse.

My analysis in a nutshell: I compute the average trading volume before and after the event date for each company. For each company, I have a series of stock market data, which I use to compute the mean around the event date.

**Data Excerpt:**

```
  PERMNO Names.Date  Volume
1  10028 02.01.2009 1.7100
2  10028 05.01.2009 1.7100
3  10028 06.01.2009 1.7100
4  10028 07.01.2009 1.7208
5  10028 08.01.2009 1.8000
```

R computes the means for me - for each of the 400 PERMNO codes.

**Example Output:**

```
EventExcerpt
#  PERMNO Event.Date Event.Date.min Event.Date.max  AvgBefore   AvgAfter
#1  10028 2009-02-06     2009-01-07     2009-03-08   1.528468   1.066490
#2  14093 2014-03-25     2014-02-23     2014-04-24   6.628968   5.679082
#3  35554 2015-10-07     2015-09-07     2015-11-06 119.761364 119.816087
```

I now want to statistically analyze the data with the goal of saying: Does the event have a significant influence on the trading volume by comparing the average before and after the event. If the average before is higher/lower - than I would conclude that there is a statistically significant event influence. I had an analysis like an ANOVA analysis in mind - however, I have not two subgroups here but rather two different time intervals which I want to compare and am not sure whether this works here.

Therefore, I am asking for advice which test could be applied here to achieve the goal I described above.